# AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400> when testing in junit

Tags: spring-mvc, junit5

My controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/ecotox", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getEcotox(@RequestParam("core") List<String> core, @RequestParam("date") List<String> date,
        @RequestParam("state") String state, @RequestParam("area") List<String> area,
        @RequestParam("type") List<String> type, @RequestParam("analyt") String analyt,
        @RequestParam("wp") String wp, @RequestParam("subDesc") String subDesc,
        @RequestParam("anaMonitor") List<String> anaMonitor, @RequestParam("ecoMonitor") List<String> ecoMonitor,
        @RequestParam("subType") List<String> subType, @RequestParam("needed") List<String> needed,
        @RequestParam("notify") List<String> notify, @RequestParam("available") List<String> available,
        @RequestParam("phase") List<String> phase, @RequestParam("subAvailable") List<String> subAvailable,
        @RequestParam("subShipped") List<String> subShipped, @RequestParam("external") List<String> external,
        @RequestParam("valid") List<String> valid, @RequestParam("contract") List<String> contract) {
        FilterInputModel model = new FilterInputModel(core, date, state, type, area, analyt, wp, subDesc,
        anaMonitor, ecoMonitor, subType, needed, notify, available, phase, subAvailable, subShipped, external, valid, contract);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(vaultService.getFilteredFields(model), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

My ControllerTest:

```
@Test
void getEcotoxTest() throws Exception {

List<Object> response = new ArrayList<>();
when(vaultServiceTest.getFilteredFields(model))
        .thenReturn(response);

this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/ecotox")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .accept("application/json"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andExpect(result -> assertEquals(response, result.getAsyncResult()));
}
```

**EDIT:**
And here's an error Message:

```
Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
Expected :200
Actual   :400
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
    at hr.ogcs.ltt.api.lttapi.controller.LttControllerTest.getEcotoxTest(LttControllerTest.java:84)

    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
```

When I call the method I got java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400> error.
I'm using Jackson.

Comment: Can you specify conrete error message? And, I suppose best practice is replace such big list of params by one DTO

Comment: @AntonTokmakov >> Hey Anton, thanks for your reply. I've edited my post and I've added an error message.

Comment: Maybe you have a null at some list fields and jackson can not convert it. Another piece of advice: why do you use `vaultServiceTest` in mock? Is it real class or test class? In mock you should use real class name.

Comment: @AntonTokmakov >> No, there is no null value, that was the first thing I was into. I've changed vaultServiceTest to vaultService, thank you for the tip. The problem is still very real, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: Try to specify all params in your request in the following way                 `.param("file", filename)`